# Reading a PDF with pyPdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I need to read a full PDF and put it in a variable to extract some pieces of text.

My code is:

```
arquivo_pdf = 'D:\PYTHON\PREFEITURA_SP\ATA40221.pdf'
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(arquivo_pdf)
total_paginas = int((len(pdf.pages)))

for pag in range(total_paginas):
    pagina = pdf.pages[pag]
    conteudo_pagina = pagina.extract_text()
    arquivo += conteudo_pagina

    print(arquivo)
```

The PDF file has 18 pages. When I run this code, it repeats the first 3 pages lots of times.

Trying to understand the problem, I put the page number manually to check the resulsts as below:

```
pagina = pdf.pages[3]
    conteudo_pagina = pagina.extract_text()

    print(conteudo_pagina)
```

When I try page, 0, 1 and 2, I got results, after of page 3, pyPDF2, returns me an empty page, but, of course, I have checked the file and I have 18 pages.

A variable with all pages of pdf.

Comment: the code looks sufficiently good. so i am wondering if there is something different about the PDF file compared to other PDF files.

Comment: After page 3, is there still some text that can be selected with the cursor ? If it is from a scanned image, it won't be extractable without an OCR.

Comment: @matleg: you are right. After page 3, the text is a scanned document page, which seemed to be a text. OMG, how didnt I see that?

Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author didn't see that it was an OCR problem, not a PDF text extraction problem.

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated, use pypdf. One reason why I deprecated PyPDF2 is that people get the capitalization wrong all the time.